# Why is the word 'narrow' an antonym to the word 'emphatic'?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, antonyms

I have been doing some antonym and synonym exercises as part of my preparation for a verbal reasoning test, and I was asked to pick an antonym for the word emphatic. There were four choices given to pick from:

1) denial

2)vehement

3)conclusive

4)narrow

In the answers it is stated that the word narrow is the antonym because the definition for the word emphatic is vigorous and decisive, and the opposite of the second if these is 'narrow' i.e. they won by a narrow margin.

I don't understand the word choice or the explanation behind it. Please could someone be kind enough to explain this to me.

ANY help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I'm on your side. The test is screwy. The definition of emphatic is using emphasis in speech or action; forceful or insistent. There's no definition of narrow that really qualifies as an antonym. Did the test instructions say to pick the *best* as opposed to the *correct* answer?

Comment: Tests are imperfect, and this one seems to have been generated by a computer. No literate human would describe *narrow* as an antonym for *emphatic* without tons of qualifying context. Even with that, it's a stretch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow! They are expecting a lot in this quiz. It is more like a cryptic crossword clue.

1. *emphatic* is an adjective, *denial* is a noun (thus they can't be antonyms)
2. *vehement* is a near synonym for *emphatic* - they are not opposites
3. *conclusive* describes the correctness of a statement, *emphatic* describes how it was made

That only leaves (4).

The explanation that it is an antonym in the context of elections is very restrictive and requires you to have much general knowledge as well as knowing the definitions.

P.S.  One of your tags is **meaning-in-context**. You didn't give us any context. Was the question preceded by a text about elections?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. The question did not have any context in it - I incorrectly included that tag. Apologies!

Comment: @Anonaanon - No worries. By the way, you can edit your question to delete the tag if you so wish.

Comment: I doubt that most native English speakers would pick "narrow" as the antonym of "emphatic" (absent some context, at least).

Answer (score 0):

It's just idiom and is a fair enough test for fluent speakers. An emphatic win is a win by a large margin. A win that emphasizes or highlights the difference between the winner and the other contestants, rubs it in, almost. Like a winning by an innings and 500 runs in cricket. It's the opposite of a narrow win. You are contrasting various types of wins, not wins vs losses.  In this assumed context, b and c are synonyms of emphatic and a is your wild card.

Comment: It's hardly a fair test even for native speakers when they don't give any context. Even with context, ‘emphatic win’ is not a very idiomatic collocation (collocations like ‘decisive win’ and ‘landslide win’ are about 15–20 times more common if you Ngram them). It's like asking for an antonym of _fake_ and then having the antonym be either _spread_ or _audiate_. Yes, both make sense as antonyms in the right context, but no one—fluent, native, or otherwise—would think of the right context if it isn't given.